# SOAP .WSDL file could not be implemented in ASP.NET but online testing tools work fine

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, soap, wsdl

I am trying to reach a SOAP service of my university to get the information of all students. I have received the .wsdl file and tried to implement in Visual Studio 2015.

I added a new Service Reference, pasted the url of the wsdl file and have unchecked the "Reuse types in in all referenced assemblies" checkbox.

I have looked into many solutions here, but none could help right now. I am starting to think, that the .wsdl file is incorrect, but sadly I just cannot find the error.

I have edited out the actual address of my university.

The warnings are all about minOccurs and maxOccurs appearing in  elements.

The **errors** are that the wsdl:binding elements have to have literal values in the soapbind:body element. (rough translation, sorry...) But this is the first time i am working with these files and I have no idea what I am supposed to change.

Here are the errors in German for reference:

> Ein wsdl:binding-Element in einer Beschreibung MUSS den literal-Wert für das Verwendungsattribut in allen soapbind:body-, soapbind:fault-, soapbind:header- und soapbind:headerfault-Elementen verwenden.
>
> - Das soapbind:body-Eingabeelement des getStudentFromUid-Vorgangs in portType-Objekt 'ConfigBinding' von Namespace '[URL]'.
>
>   - Das soapbind:body-Ausgabeelement des getStudentFromUid-Vorgangs für das portType-Objekt 'ConfigBinding' von Namespace '[URL]'.
>   - Das soapbind:body-Eingabeelement des getStudentFromMatrikelnummer-Vorgangs in portType-Objekt 'ConfigBinding' von Namespace '[URL]'.
>   - Das soapbind:body-Ausgabeelement des getStudentFromMatrikelnummer-Vorgangs für das portType-Objekt 'ConfigBinding' von Namespace '[URL]'.
>   - Das soapbind:body-Eingabeelement des getStudentFromStudiengang-Vorgangs in portType-Objekt 'ConfigBinding' von Namespace '[URL]'.
>   - Das soapbind:body-Ausgabeelement des getStudentFromStudiengang-Vorgangs für das portType-Objekt 'ConfigBinding' von Namespace '[URL]'.

```html
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8' ?>
<wsdl:definitions xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:mime="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/mime/" xmlns:tns="http://[URL]" xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:http="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/http/" targetNamespace="http://[URL]"
xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/">

  <wsdl:message name="GetStudentFromUidRequest">
    <wsdl:part minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="student_uid" type="s:string" />
    <wsdl:part minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="authentifizierung" type="tns:GetAuthentifizierung" />
  </wsdl:message>

  <wsdl:message name="GetStudentFromUidResponse">
    <wsdl:part minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="GetStudentFromUid" type="tns:Student" />
  </wsdl:message>

  <wsdl:message name="GetStudentFromMatrikelnummerRequest">
    <wsdl:part minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="student_uid" type="s:string" />
    <wsdl:part minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="authentifizierung" type="tns:GetAuthentifizierung" />
  </wsdl:message>

  <wsdl:message name="GetStudentFromMatrikelnummerResponse">
    <wsdl:part minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="GetStudentFromUid" type="tns:Student" />
  </wsdl:message>


  <wsdl:message name="GetStudentFromStudiengangRequest">
    <wsdl:part minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="studiengang" type="s:string" />
    <wsdl:part minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="semester" type="s:string" />
    <wsdl:part minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="verband" type="s:string" />
    <wsdl:part minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="gruppe" type="s:string" />
    <wsdl:part minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="authentifizierung" type="tns:GetAuthentifizierung" />
  </wsdl:message>

  <wsdl:message name="GetStudentFromStudiengangResponse">
    <wsdl:part minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="GetStudentFromStudiengang" type="tns:ArrayOfStudentItem" />
  </wsdl:message>

  <s:complexType name="ArrayOfStudentItem">
    <s:sequence>
      <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" name="StudentItem" nillable="true" type="tns:Student" />
    </s:sequence>
  </s:complexType>

  <s:complexType name="Student">
    <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="studiengang_kz" type="s:string" />
    <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="person_id" type="s:string" />
    <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="semester" type="s:string" />
    <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="verband" type="s:string" />
    <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="gruppe" type="s:string" />
    <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="vorname" type="s:string" />
    <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="nachname" type="s:string" />
    <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="uid" type="s:string" />
    <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="status" type="s:string" />
    <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="personenkennzeichen" type="s:string" />
    <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="email" type="s:string" />
  </s:complexType>

  <s:complexType name="GetAuthentifizierung">
    <s:sequence>
      <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="username" type="s:string" />
      <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="passwort" type="s:string" />
    </s:sequence>
  </s:complexType>

  <wsdl:portType name="ConfigPortType">
    <wsdl:operation name="getStudentFromUid">
      <wsdl:input message="tns:GetStudentFromUidRequest" />
      <wsdl:output message="tns:GetStudentFromUidResponse" />
    </wsdl:operation>
    <wsdl:operation name="getStudentFromMatrikelnummer">
      <wsdl:input message="tns:GetStudentFromMatrikelnummerRequest" />
      <wsdl:output message="tns:GetStudentFromMatrikelnummerResponse" />
    </wsdl:operation>
    <wsdl:operation name="getStudentFromStudiengang">
      <wsdl:input message="tns:GetStudentFromStudiengangRequest" />
      <wsdl:output message="tns:GetStudentFromStudiengangResponse" />
    </wsdl:operation>
  </wsdl:portType>

  <wsdl:binding name="ConfigBinding" type="tns:ConfigPortType">
    <soap:binding style="rpc" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" />
    <wsdl:operation name="getStudentFromUid">
      <soap:operation soapAction="https://cis.[URL]/soap/getStudentFromUid" />
      <wsdl:input>
        <soap:body use="encoded" namespace="http://[URL]" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" />
      </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output>
        <soap:body use="encoded" namespace="http://[URL]" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" />
      </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
    <wsdl:operation name="getStudentFromMatrikelnummer">
      <soap:operation soapAction="https://cis.[URL]/soap/getStudentFromMatrikelnummer" />
      <wsdl:input>
        <soap:body use="encoded" namespace="http://[URL]" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" />
      </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output>
        <soap:body use="encoded" namespace="http://[URL]" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" />
      </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
    <wsdl:operation name="getStudentFromStudiengang">
      <soap:operation soapAction="https://cis.[URL]/soap/getStudentFromStudiengang" />
      <wsdl:input>
        <soap:body use="encoded" namespace="http://[URL]" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" />
      </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output>
        <soap:body use="encoded" namespace="http://[URL]" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" />
      </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
  </wsdl:binding>

  <wsdl:service name="Student">
    <wsdl:port name="ConfigWebservicePort" binding="tns:ConfigBinding">
      <soap:address location="https://cis.[URL]//soap/student.soap.php?0.12187700 1480588994" />
    </wsdl:port>
  </wsdl:service>
</wsdl:definitions>
```

I would appreciate any help that could lead me to what I am supposed to do...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I have tried a few things and it turned out to be the wsdl file being incompatible with the php soap service.

Our university only tested the soap client with a php tool and informed me that there were no ASP.NET tests.

I had to rewrite the entire .wsdl to make it compatible with the "Add Service Reference..." function of Visual Studio.

After that it seems to work now.